# How to write depth to a texture and read it on the next pass on a shader in DirectX11?

Tags: graphics, directx, shader, directx-11, sharpdx

I'm programming a two-pass effect in DirectX 11 (SharpDX). It's supposed to write the depth to a texture in the first pass and then use that texture to extract data on the second one in the pixel shader.

What I get is a white screen, with nothing but the interface and I don't know why nothing is being printed. What could be the problem? I would say I should get at least something from the Depth Texture. Is there an easier way to obtain what I'm aiming for?

For information about what I'm doing:

This is how I'm setting the depth texture values:

```
this.depthBuffer = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Format = Format.R32_Typeless,
            ArraySize = 1,
            MipLevels = 1,
            Width = (int)host.ActualWidth,
            Height = (int)host.ActualHeight,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
        });

this.depthBufferShaderResourceView = new ShaderResourceView(this.device, this.depthBuffer, new ShaderResourceViewDescription()
        {
            Format = Format.R32_Float,
            Dimension = ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D,
            Texture2D = new ShaderResourceViewDescription.Texture2DResource()
            {
                MipLevels = 1,
                MostDetailedMip = 0,
            }
        });
var depthStencilDesc = new DepthStencilStateDescription()
        {
            DepthComparison = Comparison.LessEqual,
            DepthWriteMask = global::SharpDX.Direct3D11.DepthWriteMask.All,
            IsDepthEnabled = true,
        };
```

And here is how I sample the depth in the .fx file:

```
int3 posTex = int3(input.p.xy, 0);
float depthPixel = DepthTexture.Load(posTex);
float4 color = float4(depthPixel, depthPixel , depthPixel, 1.0f );
return color;
```

And here the way I'm now setting the Depth Buffer stencil view as a Render Target in 2 passes. In the first I try to set the depthstencilview as a target. In the second pass I'm trying to set teh depth texture as a shader resource to read from it.

```
this.device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(this.vertexBuffer, LinesVertex.SizeInBytes, 0));

// PASS 0
this.device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthBufferStencilView);
this.device.ImmediateContext.ClearDepthStencilView(this.depthBufferStencilView,     DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth | DepthStencilClearFlags.Stencil, 1.0f, 0);
this.technique.GetPassByIndex(0).Apply(this.device.ImmediateContext);
this.device.ImmediateContext.DrawIndexed(this.geometry.Indices.Length, 0, 0);

// PASS 1
this.device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.ResetTargets(); // unbinding the depthStencilView

this.device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(this.vertexBuffer, LinesVertex.SizeInBytes, 0));
this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable = effect.GetVariableByName("DepthTexture").AsShaderResource();
this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable.SetResource(this.depthBufferShaderResourceView);
this.technique.GetPassByIndex(1).Apply(this.device.ImmediateContext);
this.device.ImmediateContext.DrawIndexed(this.geometry.Indices.Length, 0, 0);
```

Finally, this is how I set the two passes in the .fx file:

```
technique11 RenderMyTechnique
{
pass P0
{   

SetDepthStencilState( DSSDepthLessEqual, 0 );
SetVertexShader     ( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VShader() ) );
    SetHullShader       ( NULL );
    SetDomainShader     ( NULL );        
    SetGeometryShader   ( NULL  );
SetPixelShader      ( NULL );
}

pass P1
{
SetDepthStencilState( DSSDepthLessEqual, 0 );
SetVertexShader     ( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VShader() ) );
    SetHullShader       ( NULL );
    SetDomainShader     ( NULL );        
    SetGeometryShader   ( CompileShader( gs_4_0, GShader() ) );
SetPixelShader      ( CompileShader( ps_4_0, PShader() ) );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
this.device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.ResetTargets();
```

After that your perform your draw directly, you don't bind any render target to it, so you need to call:

```
this.device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(renderView);
```

renderview being any rendertarget view (can be your swapchain). For the moment you do a draw but to "nothing".

Second potential issue, you redraw the same model, but with no depth stencil, so results might be different (specially since in one version you use a Geometry Shader and not in the other one). So your depth data from previous pass might not be valid at all.